# BASH Modulus on Date switches

Tags: bash, date, modulo

Here's my code

```
#!/bin/bash
#This works
MIN_SEQ_NO=$(date +%M)
echo "Minute" $MIN_SEQ_NO
MOD_VAL=$((MIN_SEQ_NO % 5))
echo "Minute Mod 5:" $MOD_VAL


#This works
DAY_SEQ_NO=$(date +%d)
echo "Day of Month:" $DAY_SEQ_NO
MOD_VAL=$((DAY_SEQ_NO % 5))
echo "Day of Month Mod 5:" $MOD_VAL

#But not this
DOY_SEQ_NO=$(date +%j)
echo "Day of Year " $DOY_SEQ_NO
MOD_VAL=$((DOY_SEQ_NO % 5))
echo "Day of Year Mod 5:" $MOD_VAL
```

Since today is the 12th, I'm expecting **2**.
How can I use bash modulus on `date +%j`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`012` in a math context is treated as an octal number because of the leading zero. The equivalent decimal expression is `10 % 5` and outputs 0.

You either have to strip the leading zero:

```
MOD_VAL=$(( ${DOY_SEQ_NO#0} % 5 ))
```

Or force decimal interpretation:

```
MOD_VAL=$(( 10#${DOY_SEQ_NO} % 5 ))
```

Comment: Or: use `date +%-j` to suppress leading zeroes